# Generating xml ouput file by using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

My input data is present in csv file and need to generate XML output file based on data available in input file. I am trying to implement this requirement with python. I have tried the below code but not getting required output.

**Input Data(Input.csv file):**

```
CustID,CardNo
A00001,C000000001  
A00001,C000000002  
A00002,C000000003
```

**I have tried below code:**

```
import csv
import io
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict

def generate_xml(input_file, output_file):

    # Read input data from the file
    with open(input_file, 'r') as file:
        input_data = file.readlines()

    cards_per_custid = defaultdict(list)
    for line in csv.DictReader(input_data):
        cards_per_custid[line["CustID"]].append(line["CardNo"])

    root = ET.Element(
    "ReceivableAccounting",
    attrib={"xmlns": "http://www.sample.com/testing"},
    )
    for cust_id, cards in sorted(cards_per_custid.items()):
        card_el = ET.SubElement(root, "Card")
        header = ET.SubElement(card_el, "CustHolderHeader")
        ET.SubElement(header, "CustID").text = cust_id
    for card_no in cards:
        line = ET.SubElement(card_el, "CardLine")
        ET.SubElement(line, "CardDetail").text = card_no

    tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
    ET.indent(tree)
    tree.write(output_file)

# Example usage:
input_file = "Input.csv"
output_file = "output.xml"
generate_xml(input_file, output_file)
```

**Generating the below result:**

```
<ReceivableAccounting xmlns="http://www.sample.com/testing">
  <Card>
    <CustHolderHeader>
      <CustID>A00001</CustID>
    </CustHolderHeader>
  </Card>
  <Card>
    <CustHolderHeader>
      <CustID>A00003</CustID>
    </CustHolderHeader>
    <CardLine>
      <CardDetail>C000000003</CardDetail>
    </CardLine>
  </Card>
```

**Expecting the below result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ReceivableAccounting xmlns=http://www.sample.com/testing>
  <Card>
     <CustHolderHeader>
        <CustID>A00001</CustID>
     </CustHolderHeader>
     <CardLine>
        <CardDetail>C000000001</CardDetail>
     </CardLine>
       <CardLine>
        <CardDetail>C000000002</CardDetail>
     </CardLine> 
  </Card>
  <Card>
     <CustHolderHeader>
        <CustID>A00002</CustID>
     </CustHolderHeader>
     <CardLine>
        <CardDetail>C000000003</CardDetail>
     </CardLine>  
     </Card>
```

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: Is the input file always sorted by `CustID`?

Comment: Decide for one Python version and remove the wrong tag.

Comment: Data will not be sorted. Please find the current output below.

<root><CustID>CardNo</CustID><A00001>C000000001</A00001><A00001>C000000002</A00001><A00003>C000000003</A00003></root>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure thing.

I've inlined your example data into an `io.StringIO()`, but you can just as well substitute an open file handle. Note that the `xmlns` handling I'm doing here is not 100% the correct way to do it, but it works for your example case.

```
import csv
import io
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict

input_file = io.StringIO(
    """
CustID,CardNo
A00001,C000000001
A00001,C000000002
A00002,C000000003
""".strip()
)

cards_per_custid = defaultdict(list)
for line in csv.DictReader(input_file):
    cards_per_custid[line["CustID"]].append(line["CardNo"])

root = ET.Element(
    "ReceivableAccounting",
    attrib={"xmlns": "http://www.sample.com/testing"},
)
for cust_id, cards in sorted(cards_per_custid.items()):
    card_el = ET.SubElement(root, "Card")
    header = ET.SubElement(card_el, "CustHolderHeader")
    ET.SubElement(header, "CustID").text = cust_id
    for card_no in cards:
        line = ET.SubElement(card_el, "CardLine")
        ET.SubElement(line, "CardDetail").text = card_no

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
ET.indent(tree)

print(ET.tostring(root, encoding="unicode"))
```

This prints

```
<ReceivableAccounting xmlns="http://www.sample.com/testing">
  <Card>
    <CustHolderHeader>
      <CustID>A00001</CustID>
    </CustHolderHeader>
    <CardLine>
      <CardDetail>C000000001</CardDetail>
    </CardLine>
    <CardLine>
      <CardDetail>C000000002</CardDetail>
    </CardLine>
  </Card>
  <Card>
    <CustHolderHeader>
      <CustID>A00002</CustID>
    </CustHolderHeader>
    <CardLine>
      <CardDetail>C000000003</CardDetail>
    </CardLine>
  </Card>
</ReceivableAccounting>
```

Comment: I have tried to include input and output files in the provided code and did not get expected output. Missing card details for first cust id in the output file. 
   
<ReceivableAccounting xmlns="http://www.sample.com/testing">    
  <Card>    
    <CustHolderHeader>    
      <CustID>A00001</CustID>    
    </CustHolderHeader>    
  </Card>    
  <Card>    
    <CustHolderHeader>    
      <CustID>A00003</CustID>    
    </CustHolderHeader>    
    <CardLine>    
      <CardDetail>C000000003</CardDetail>    
    </CardLine>    
  </Card>

Comment: TBH, that's not possible. There wouldn't be a record in `cards_per_custid` if a card wasn't read for that custid.

Comment: I am not able to share the entire code in the comments section because of character limit. Is there any way to share the code?

Comment: I have updated my original post with new code, please refer for the same.

Comment: You'll want to just debug your code and e.g. see what's in `cards_per_custid` for your file.